# C how to define a context that can be checked by the preprocessor

Tags: c, gcc, macros, preprocessor

On an embedded system, I have a function, that shall not be called from interrupt-context. I would like to ensure that it gets checked in compile time. I thought, it would be nice if the preprocessor could check this. I think of something like this:

```
/* function that shall not be called from interrupt-context */
void function_not_to_call_from_isr(void)
{
    #ifdef INTERRUPT_CONTEXT
        #error This shall not be called from interrupt context!
    #endif
    // ... stuff ...
}

void someISRfunction(void)
{
#define INTERRUPT_CONTEXT
    // here, the check can be performed
    function_not_to_call_from_isr();
#undef INTERRUPT_CONTEXT
}
```

My question is, can some magic be done so that I do not have to manually define/undefine the INTERRUPT_CONTEXT?
like:

```
#define INTERRUPT_SERVICE_ROUTINE(funcName) void funcName(void) // magic needed here...
```

Any idea?

Comment: Why don't you simply disable interrupt which is calling this function?

Comment: I simply would like to ensure that this function does not get written into an ISR context by another programmer/collegue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant as all `#define`s are expanded before actual compilation. You need a variable

```
#define INTERRUPT_CONTEXT_ENTRY do {frominterrupt++;} while(0)
#define INTERRUPT_CONTEXT_EXIT  do {frominterrupt--;} while(0)
#define FROM_INTERRUPT  (frominterrupt > 0)
#define ISR_PANIC (frominterrupt < 0)

volatile int frominterrupt = 0;


void interrupt_handler()
{
    INTERRUPT_CONTEXT_ENTRY;
    /* do something*/
    INTERRUPT_CONTEXT_EXIT;
}

void function_not_to_call_from_isr(void)
{
    if(ISR_PANIC)
    {
         /* start the suicide procedure */
         /* your program is dead anyway */
    }

    if(FROM_INTERRUPT)
    {
        /* do something - illegal call */
    }
    else
    {
        /* do normall stuff */
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you need `do while`? Can't you do without it?

Comment: simply declares a block of code, use normal C syntax (`;` after the statement), works in ifs and loops etc etc

Comment: But this approach is also not (as mine) compile time as this is not possible.

Comment: Yes, this is a solution, but my goal would have been to avoid writing this INTERRUPT_CONTEXT_ENTRY/INTERRUPT_CONTEXT_EXIT manually into the interrupt handler. I mean, like if there was some macro-magic, that does something like decorators in python.

Comment: There is no way to make programs idiot resistant I afraid. If someone wants to call function from the interrupt - he will and no one will stop him

Comment: You should rewrite your defines as: `#define INTERRUPT_CONTEXT_ENTRY do {frominterrupt++;} while(0)` and `#define INTERRUPT_CONTEXT_EXIT  do { if (frominterrupt) frominterrupt--;} while(0)`.

Comment: @tilz0R if someone has exited handler more times that he has entered - is it is quite strange

Comment: hah, so you will do aynthing except listen to me. Your ego is quite high ;) Deleting comments..

Comment: @tilz0R this if hides some errors. same as not necessary casts. At least you can catch them.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to prevent function to be called from context, no this is not possible in preprocessor using the way you want, specially not on compile time.

For specific architecture, you can check if you are in interrupt context and then decide what do to. Bottom example is for ARM Cortex-M with CMSIS code.

```
void func_prohibited_in_isr(void) {
    if (__get_IPSR()) {
        //Called from IRQ, return
        return;
    }
    //Other code, executed when function is not called from IRQ
}

//IRQ function for peripheral
void IRQ_Handler(void) {
    func_prohibited_in_isr(); //Will do nothing when called
}
```

So you have to find out how to check for specific architecture if you are in IRQ context.

Comment: not too portable :). And he did mention any architecture